# Style preference for binary operators with long lines

Tags: coding-style, binary-operators

Most style guides, such as Google's, for C++ recommend a maximum line length of 80 characters as well as relevant guidelines for function calls such that the function call is formatted correctly.

For example, [here](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Function_Calls) is what Google's style guide has to say on the matter:

> Function calls have the following format:
>
> ```
> bool retval = DoSomething(argument1, argument2, argument3);
> ```
>
> If the arguments do not all fit on one line, they should be broken up
>   onto multiple lines, with each subsequent line aligned with the first
>   argument. Do not add spaces after the open paren or before the close
>   paren:
>
> ```
> bool retval = DoSomething(averyveryveryverylongargument1,
>                           argument2, argument3);
> ```
>
> If the function has many arguments, consider having one per line if
>   this makes the code more readable:
>
> ```
> bool retval = DoSomething(argument1,
>                           argument2,
>                           argument3,
>                           argument4);
> ```
>
> Arguments may optionally all be placed on subsequent lines, with one
>   line per argument:
>
> ```
> if (...) {
>   ...
>   ...
>   if (...) {
>     DoSomething(
>         argument1,  // 4 space indent
>         argument2,
>         argument3,
>         argument4);
>   }
> ```
>
> In particular, this should be done if the function signature is so
>   long that it cannot fit within the maximum line length.

What isn't discussed is what is preferable for binary operators. This is a matter of style, so there's not a particularly correct answer, but I was hoping to get some opinions on what people prefer in the case of binary operators with long variable names or expressions.

For example, consider the simple case

```
result = reallyReallyReallyReallyLongVariableName * otherReallyReallyLongVariableName;
```

There are three formats that jump out at me:

```
// #1: The assignment operator is treated as a call for the sake of formatting.

result = 
    reallyReallyReallyReallyLongVariableName * otherReallyReallyLongVariableName;

// #2: The binary operator is positioned under the equal sign, my preference.

result = reallyReallyReallyReallyLongVariableName
       * otherReallyReallyLongVariableName;

// #3: There is basic indentation of 4 spaces.

result = reallyReallyReallyReallyLongVariableName
    * otherReallyReallyLongVariableName;
```

The first two are a bit more intuitive in my opinion, and [Zend Framework Style Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html#coding-standard.coding-style.strings.string-concatenation) recommends the format of #2 for repeated concatenation of strings in PHP.

As for the third, [Pear's PHP Style Guide](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.funcalls.php) recommends starting new lines with the `->` operator in the case of repeated function calls, which is somewhat loosely analogous to a binary operator.

I personally prefer the second, but I was just wondering what others' opinions are.

Comment: I too wish that there existed a more commonly accepted style.  Any of the usual alternatives you mention is acceptable.  It will be nice when convention finally settles on one.  In the interim, when patching or adding to code written by others I adhere to their style.  In my own code, I prefer a half-indent of two spaces for a broken line -- which is not one of your options.

Comment: I didn't consider a 2 space indent because the style guide I mostly adhere to is Google's and they're pretty resolute that you should have 2 space indent for normal control structure (like a for loop) and a 4 space indent for any stylistic spacing. I do think #3 (which is more or less the same as yours) is the most versatile as #2 would look bad if you need multiple lines with various things on it, like binary operators on function calls that need their own formatting.

Comment: I happen to have taught the introductory C++ programming course to classrooms of engineering undergraduates four times.  I tried as hard as I reasonably could to avoid influencing the students with personal coding quirks and preferences of my own.  Every term, I changed the style of indentation of my classroom examples to try to be more standard, until it dawned on me that no standard existed.  Your question thus is a significant question to me.  I am glad that you have asked it.